# Values() of HashMap returning incorrect output

Tags: java

To my understanding, the following code should print `true` in both cases, since values are some not changed.

However, when I run the following code it is printing `true` and `false`:

```
   public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Boolean> map1 = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
        HashMap<String, Boolean> map2 = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

        map1.put("true", Boolean.TRUE);
        map1.put("false", Boolean.FALSE);

        map2.put("true", Boolean.TRUE);
        map2.put("false", Boolean.FALSE);

        System.out.println(map1.equals(map2)); // prints true as expected

        // prints false even though the values are indeed equal:
        System.out.println(map1.values().equals(map2.values()));
    }

}
```

Can some one help me understand why it is printing `false` in second case.

Comment: `map.values()` returns a `Collection`. You do not know anything about its implementation. Hence, you cannot expect it to return true just because the element inside are equal.

Comment: The reason is that the `values` returned does not implement `equals()`.  Whatever version of equals it is using does not consider your two maps' values collections to be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashMap.values()` returns an implementation of `Collection` that doesn't override `Object`'s `equals`, therefore the comparison returns `false`, since the default implementation compares references.

```
final class Values extends AbstractCollection<V> {
    public final int size()                 { return size; }
    public final void clear()               { HashMap.this.clear(); }
    public final Iterator<V> iterator()     { return new ValueIterator(); }
    public final boolean contains(Object o) { return containsValue(o); }
    public final Spliterator<V> spliterator() {
        return new ValueSpliterator<>(HashMap.this, 0, -1, 0, 0);
    }
    public final void forEach(Consumer<? super V> action) {
        Node<K,V>[] tab;
        if (action == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        if (size > 0 && (tab = table) != null) {
            int mc = modCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; ++i) {
                for (Node<K,V> e = tab[i]; e != null; e = e.next)
                    action.accept(e.value);
            }
            if (modCount != mc)
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to avoid answering such duplicates if possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
 System.out.println(map1.equals(map2)); // prints true as expected
```

It is because [HashMap's equals() method overiden](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractMap.java#AbstractMap.equals%28java.lang.Object%29) such a way that it is checks the keys and values.

```
 System.out.println(map1.values().equals(map2.values()));// false
```

Where as when you do `.values()` you are getting a Collection object which doesn't ovveride equals and  hence the default behaviour.